# Qual a origem e o sentido da expressão "de nada"

Tags: significado, expressões, português-brasileiro

***IN ENGLISH***

In ptBR, we usually say **"de nada"** in reply to **"obrigado/a"**

e.g.

> - A. "Obrigado pela carona"  (Thank you for giving me a lift.)
> - B. "De nada."  (You're welcome)

I understand "obrigado" as a short form for "se você me pedir um favor, serei obrigado a lhe retribuir (if you ask me to do you a favor, I will feel obliged to repay it)  **It seems to me, therefore, that the right reply to "obrigado" would be "disponha" or something like that.**

e.g.

> A. Obrigado por me ajudar no trabalho hoje. (Thank you for helping me do my tasks today)
>
> B. Disponha. (Feel free to ask again)

**How did "de nada" originate and what does it stand for?**

> 

,

***IN PORTUGUESE***

No Brasil, nós somos acostumados a responder "de nada" quando alguém nos agradece.

Ex.:

> A: Obrigado pela carona.
>   B: De nada.

Sei que "Obrigado" é como se fosse uma abreviação de

> Se você me pedir um favor, serei **obrigado** a lhe retribuir.

Por isso, me parece que a expressão correta para se responder um "obrigado" seria "disponha" ou algo do gênero.

Ex.:

> A: Obrigado por me ajudar no trabalho hoje.
>   B: Disponha.

Como surgiu essa forma de responder? E o que quer dizer "de nada"?

---

<sub>Observação: Por favor, sintam-se a vontade para traduzir a pergunta para o inglês. Eu não me sinto confortável escrevendo em inglês.</sub>

Comment: O [segundo parágrafo](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/denada-de-nada-ou-dinada/) possui uma explicação de "o que quer dizer "de nada". Agora, como surgiu eu não sei lhe dizer.

Comment: Pelo que lembro, 'Obrigado' é a forma curta de 'Estou obrigado'; você me fez um favor, e eu me sinto obrigado a retribuir no futuro. Da mesma maneira, 'de nada' é a forma curta de 'Não estás obrigado de nada', inferindo que o esforço foi ínfimo.

Comment: @OnoSendai O problema dessa teoria é que "obrigado" se usa com "a", não "de".

Comment: Achei interessante essa teoria @OnoSendai e Randrade, porém não faz muito sentido dizer "não estás obrigado de nada" ao invés de "não estás obrigado a nada".

Comment: E se fosse "por nada" em vez de "de nada"? *"Se você me pedir um favor, serei **obrigado** a retribuir-lhe."* em resposta *"Fiz de bom grado, não fiz isso a pensar em nada em troca, ou seja, fiz isso **por nada**"*

Comment: As preposições são muito flexíveis. "Obrigado de nada" soa-nos estranho, mas pode ter sido uma frase normal séculos atrás. Não estou a dizer que foi, mas eu não descarto já a hipótese do "obrigado de nada."

Comment: Notem que em francês a expressão é a mesma: "de rien".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Não consegui descobrir quando é que ***de nada*** começou a ser usado como resposta a um agradecimento. Mas no século XVIII, possivelmente até mesmo no limiar do século XX, a frase “Vossa Mercê não está obrigada de nada” não suscitaria qualquer estranheza e seria entendida como “Vossa Mercê não está obrigada por nada” ou “Vossa Mercê não tem qualquer obrigação.” Portanto, fosse qual fosse a origem de *de nada*, a sua adoção seria facilitada por *obrigado de nada* ser no passado, ao contrário do que se passa atualmente, imediatamente compreensível.

[Esta questão existe também no SE Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/why-is-de-nada-used-as-a-response-to-gracias) sem uma explicação cabal da preposição ***de***. Também para o falante moderno do castelhano a preposição *por* seria mais natural. Um comentário à pergunta diz que o *de nada* castelhano vem do francês *de rien*, que uma resposta à [questão equivalente no SE French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/940/pourquoi-r%C3%A9pond-on-de-rien-%C3%A0-merci) diz ser um redução de *ne me remerciez de rien*.

Vontando ao português, ***obrigado*** usou-se até pelo menos ao século XVIII com a preposição ***de***. *Obrigado de* era entendido como *obrigado por, forçado por*. É possível que *obrigado de* fosse assim compreendido ainda no limiar do século XX:

> Logo publicamente, ***obrigado do*** poder divino, confessou que era o demónio do inferno, o qual havia catorze anos que andava naquele castelo, ([Francisco Saraiva de Sousa, *Báculo pastoral de flores*, 1624](http://porbase.bnportugal.pt/ipac20/ipac.jsp?session=1TC83258M9309.173967&profile=porbase&uri=link=3100027%7E!9742836%7E!3100024%7E!3100022&aspect=basic_search&menu=search&ri=1&source=%7E!bnp&term=Baculo%20pastoral%20de%20flores%20de%20exemplos%20divinos...%20dedicado%20ao...%20Dom%20Theodosio%20segundo%20deste%20nome%20Duque%20de%20Bargan%C3%A7a%20%5Bsic%5D&index=ALTITLE))
>
> Nos 14 annos de Gorgoris succedeo o incendio de troya, e hum dos que prezunciarão esta fatalidade, foy Olisses Rey de Ithaca. Este na retirada, que fazia com os seus, ***obrigado de*** huma furiosa tormenta, entrou pelo Rio Tejo [...] (Frei Manoel da Mealhada, *Promptuario historico II*, 1760.)
>
> Antônio José não só não seguiu nessa parte os modelos recentes, mas até carregou a mão sobre o que imitou de Plauto. A alegria do seu Anfitrião e da sua Alcmena é tão franca, tamanho é o alvoroço dos dous esposos, que realmente chega a ofender as leis da verossimilhança, ainda tratando-se de um caso divino. Neste ponto Antônio José foi antes inadvertido do que ***obrigado do*** gosto público. ([Machado de Assis](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machado_de_Assis), [*Críticas*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=4eHdCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT274&lpg=PT274&dq=Neste%20ponto%20Ant%C3%B4nio%20Jos%C3%A9%20antes%20inadvertido%20do%20que%20obrigado%20do%20gosto%20p%C3%BAblico&source=bl&ots=5bmGSbBRyI&sig=4sFDQUP7DzgDrvWVhgOrZCcba4s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6hovD5anJAhVDfxoKHUbEByoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Neste%20ponto%20Ant%C3%B4nio%20Jos%C3%A9%20antes%20inadvertido%20do%20que%20obrigado%20do%20gosto%20p%C3%BAblico&f=false), 1906.)

Esta ocorrência de *obrigado de* foi a única posterior ao século XVIII que encontrei com o sentido de *obrigado por*. Daí ter qualificado como apenas possível o seu uso ou compreensão no limiar do século XX. Possivelmente seria na altura um arcaísmo. Machado de Assis nasceu em 1839. Nos exemplos anteriores, é uma força exterior que obriga. Nos seguintes, o que obriga é um sentimento de gratidão. Em português moderno, poderíamos substituir o ***obrigado de*** por ***grato por***::

> O mancebo, alheio destes pensamentos, porém ***obrigado das*** mostras que lhe revelavam aquela afeição, determinou de lhe não ser ingrato ([Francisco Rodrigues Lobo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Rodrigues_Lobo), *Côrte na Aldeia e Noites de Inverno*, 1607.)
>
> Morto o Egypcio, [Antioco] renovou a guerra, e tomou Celesyria, Phenicia, e Judea. Diz Josepho, que ***obrigado do*** grande festejo com que os Judeos o receberaõ, eximira os Sacerdotes dos tributos, e lhe facultou o viverem conforme sa suas leys. (Frei Manoel da Mealhada, Promptuario historico I, 1760.)
>
> Escreve Luciano, que indo Antioco contra os Galatas, lhe appareceo em sonhos a figura de Alexandre, a qual lhe deu hum sinal de tres triangulos por sinal e penhor do vencimento; e foy assim, que quando em meyo da batalha Antioco levantou aquella figura contra os Galatas, alcançou logo vitoria; ***de que obrigado*** Antioco mandou lavrar moeda, que continha de huma parte a figura revelada de Alexandre com os tres triangulos, e da outra estas letras Gregas ??????, que se interpretárão, saude; e methaforico, vitoria. ([Francisco Manuel de Mello](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Manuel_de_Melo#Tratado_da_Ci.C3.AAncia), *[Tratado da sciencia cabala, ou Noticia da arte cabalística](http://www.fc.up.pt/fa/index.php?p=nav&f=books.0260.W_0260_000003#faimg)*, 1724.)

A passagem seguinte é a mais antiga em que eu encontrei ***obrigado*** usado praticamente como atualmente, mas em que o significado original é ainda muito explícito:

> Sabereis que é já chegado o B~reve [?] muito à minha satisfaçao e assim já nao há necessidade de fazerdes viagem tao trabalhosa. Eu vos fico tao ***obrigado***, como se efectivamente a empreendesseis e me mostrarei sempre à vossa boa vontade agradecido. ([Manoel Consciência](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Autor:Manuel_Consci%C3%AAncia), *Academia universal*, 1732)

Como nesta época se dizia *obrigado disto* e *obrigado daquilo*, seria perfeitamente possível responder ao senhor, “não tendes que ficar obrigado de nada.” Com o desaparecimento da construção *obrigado de*, não admira que o *de nada* soe um nadinha misterioso ao falante moderno do português.

As mais antigas respostas que encontrei a um agradecimento foi no final do século XIX sob a forma ***não há de quê***. Isto corresponde exatamente ao francês *il n'y a pas de quoi*. Em português poderiam ser entendidas como *não tem de que agradecer* ou *não tem de que ficar obrigado*.

> ÂNGELO (Erguendo-se e entregando o cheque) - Obrigado pela comissão do marido. ESPOSENDE - Não há de quê. ([Artur Azevedo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artur_de_Azevedo), *O Dote*, 1888.)
>
> LUÍSA - Obrigada... pela parte que me toca! DR. PEREIRA - Não há de quê! ([França Júnior](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7a_J%C3%BAnior), *As Doutoras*, 1889)

Comment: Nos teus últimos exemplos, _de_ refere-se ao substantivo, não a "obrigado".

Comment: E daí? "obrigado de uma tormenta" = "obrigado por uma tormenta".

Comment: Os exemplos do meio são convincentes e o Google Books também mostra outros tantos no século XVII e até alguns no século XIX (incluindo com o sentido de grato), mas no mínimo seria preciso mostrar que "de nada" já se usava no século XIX. Outra hipótese é ter vindo do espanhol.

Comment: Os últimos, não os primeiros: "assunto dos brindes", "caminho  das margens". "Obrigado" não vem ao caso.

Answer (score 8):

Realmente **"de nada"** é a forma mais comum de responder a quem agradece com um "muito obrigado/a" no Brasil, mas não é a única. A variante **"por nada"** também é usada e talvez seja mais fácil de entender. "De nada" seria a forma de dizer "não tens obrigação de nada, não tens obrigação alguma, não te sintas obrigado a nada" e "por nada" seria "o que eu fiz não foi nada".

Mas se nenhuma delas te agrada, temos uma variedade imensa de expressões para transmitir o mesmo.  Os paulistas gostam de dizer **"imagina!"**, assim mesmo, como uma exclamação. O significado é literal: "imagina se vou achar que tu me deves alguma coisa por isso."  Também há quem diga **"disponha"**, **"às ordens"**, **"sempre às ordens"**, **"não foi nada"**, **"que isso?"**, **"nada a agradecer"**, **"não há de quê",  ou até mesmo **ficar calado quando sabidamente aquele que agradece não espera ouvir uma resposta.** Um exemplo típico é quando deixamos alguém passar à frente na rua, ou seguramos uma porta que vai fechar e as pessoas agradecem. Agradecem mas, sendo desconhecidos, dificilmente esperam uma resposta. Um "disponha" ou "sempre às ordens" nessas situações, pode transmitir erroneamente  a intenção de se iniciar uma conversa.

Bem, as opções são muitas e a escolha fica por conta da intimidade que tu tens com o ouvinte e o tom de formalidade que desejas dar.  Como surgiram as expressões? Surgiram da necessidade de também ser educado. No entanto, chama a atenção o fato de que **em francês, a expressão é exatamente a mesma:** **"de rien"**.  **Será apenas mera coincidência?**

Answer (score 4):

O [dicionário da Real Academia Espanhola](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=nada) lista a expressão equivalente em castelhano com dois significados:

> de [nada].
>    1. **loc. adj.** De escaso valor, sin importancia. *Un librito de nada. Una cuestión de nada. Cosa de nada.*
>    2. **expr. U.** como respuesta cortés cuando a alguien le dan las gracias por algo.

E de facto em português também se por dizer "é uma coisita de nada". Poderá portanto vir daí a expressão.

Possivelmente pode até ter sido introduzida através do espanhol. Saber a data em que entrou na língua poderia dar algumas pistas sobre essa questão, bem como se outras explicações, como a do Jacinto, são plausíveis.

Answer (score 0):

Voltanto no passado, sempre que alguém firmava um compromisso com outrem, havia a 'obrigação' de cumprimento daquele oficio. Daí então, vinha a ação 'obrigada a...'.
Ex.:

- Pegue aquele objeto para mim! (há quem solicita e há uma ordem que obriga outro a fazer a ação)
- Obrigado (responde o que ordena para confirmar que se trata de uma ordem)
- Por nada? (pergunta o que faz a ação como que cobrasse por aquela ação: vou fazer mas vou receber algo?)

Ora, numa estrutura escravista, o "obrigado" e "por nada" (ou "de nada") são expressões razoavelmente plausíveis, o problema é encararmos esse diálogo no dias de hoje. Seria uma herança maldita?

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, Pedro, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências (confira as demais respostas para bons exemplos disso). Em que se baseia sua resposta?