# Obrigado você ou Obrigado eu?

Tags: expressões

Sempre tive uma dúvida e gostaria de compartilhá-la com vocês. Vamos supor que alguém lhe agradeça por algo que você tenha feito e você queira agradecê-lo também.

Um exemplo bem típico: Tenho uma loja e vendo um produto a um cliente e após a transação nós dois nos sentimos gratos, eu pela venda e ele pelo serviço.

O cliente me agradeçe a venda:

> -Obrigado!

Como devo responder a esse agradecimento?

> -Obrigado eu!
>
> -Obrigado você!

Já vi ambos os casos sendo utilizados e conversei com algumas pessoas que me sugeriram trocar a palavra **obrigado** por **grato**.

Fazendo a troca de **obrigado** por **grato** faz mais sentido utilizar "Obrigado eu" pois quem está sendo grato sou eu, mas pensado no dia a dia é muito comum utilizar "obrigado você" no sentido de ser grato pelo que o outro fez. Como seria a melhor maneira de responder?

Como eu não sei a maneira correta tenho utilizado a expressão: "Eu é que agradeço!"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu, pessoalmente, utilizo:

> Eu é que agradeço

Mas expressar gratidão também é correto:

> Grato

Uma outra forma, que acredito que seja bem regional do Rio Grande do Sul , Brasil, especialmente onde temos fronteira com o Uruguai é dizer:

> Merecido

Mas respondendo a primeira pergunta, o mais cortez seria:

> Obrigado eu

Dessa forma, estará dizendo que tu estás obrigado.

Se disser:

> Obrigado você

Pode parecer rude e também soar que a outra pessoa que tem uma obrigação com você.

Fonte: [Português - UOL](http://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/obrigado-eu-ou-obrigado-voce.html)

Comment: "Dessa forma, estará dizendo que tu estás obrigado" não seria mais correto dizer "(...) estarás dizendo que tu estás _agradecido_."

Comment: Ai que está. Se tu diz: *Obrigado eu*. No meu entender, está dizendo que não é a pessoa que te disse : *Obrigado* que está obrigada, mas tu estás. Na meu entender, *Agradecido* e *Obrigado* tem significados diferentes. Posso estar *grato* por algo, mas não preciso estar *obrigado*.

Comment: Eu também já disse "obrigado eu" (que pode ser visto como *obrigado, digo eu* ou, mais à antiga, *obrigado, sou/fico eu*), mas nunca "obrigado você/tu", que para mim não faz sentido; só se fosse *obrigado **a** você"! Obrigado* e *grato/agradecido* têm origens distintas, mas não me parece que hoje sejam entendidas com significados diferentes.

Answer (score 6):

Quando se pensa na construção da palavra *obrigado* vem de *obrigar*. Quem estaria se sentindo obrigado a fazer algo?

A forma constatada [*obrigado eu*](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1008) faz sentido, já que foi respondido o agradecimento assim **obrigando a servir seu cliente**. Este seria o dever.

Pode dizer que o agradecimento ou gratidão é um sentimento de dever que a pessoa tem em relação a outra. Possivelmente faze-lo como se fosse um elogio (*[kudos](http://www.teclasap.com.br/kudos-qual-e-a-traducao/)*). Então o obrigado seria uma forma de demonstrar quão feliz está pela vinda do cliente, pelo fato dela ser muito importante para o negócio. Está no dever de parabenizar tal atitude.

Muitas palavras sozinhas não tem significado ideal sem um tom de voz, um gesto e outras formas de expressão. Logo, se falar obrigado de forma ríspida não passará a mensagem correta, poderia ser pensado sobre isso: "Que coisa, Fulano só deu um obrigado".

Importante expressar de forma ligada com sua intenção e não se está certo ou errado. Qual seria o objetivo? Talvez somente se trabalhar em um ambiente onde ser erudito seja um requisito.

Se o **eu** soa estranho, poderia ser: *Que isso! Obrigado por ter vindo!*

Answer (score 5):

Ao contrário de outras línguas derivadas do Latim, o Português não utiliza construções que remetam ao radical de *graça* (como o *gracias* espanhol ou o *grazzi* italiano. Padrão similar ocorreu com os dias da semana, que, em Português, não fazem referência a divindades não cristãs, como ocorre em Espanhol, Italiano, Francês etc.

O termo *obrigado* que empregamos​ em Português deriva da expressão "sinto-me *obrigado* a retribuir a gentileza". Infelizmente, não sei oferecer fonte para essa informação.

Dessa forma, a expressão *obrigado você* significaria, como mencionado em outra resposta, que o seu interlocutor é quem estaria obrigado a retribuir a gentileza -- que não é o que se quis dar a entender.

Nesse sentido, *obrigado a você* teria o mesmo sentido que *obrigado eu*, a saber, *eu* estou *obrigado* a retribuir *a você* a gentileza que você acabou de me fazer.

Comment: *Obrigado* tem ou teve esse sentido, mas eu nunca encontrei a expressão (em textos antigos ou modernos) "sinto-me obrigado a retribuir a gentileza"; já encontrei foi coisas como "fico-vos obrigado": vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/qual-a-origem-e-o-sentido-da-express%C3%A3o-de-nada?rq=1)

Comment: @Jacinto, obrigado!  

Comment: Possivelmente, é um elemento de oralidade de difícil rastreio.

Comment: É verdade. Também já vi em cartas antigas, o autor despedir-se com qualquer coisa como, "sou obrigado de V. Excelência", ou coisa assim

Answer (score 3):

Quando alguém me agradece mas eu também me sinto grato e quero agradecer de volta, geralmente uso uma dessas frases:

> -Eu que agradeço (ou "Eu é que agradeço")
>
> -Obrigado eu (ou "Obrigado digo eu")

As formas entre parênteses são um pouco mais enfáticas. Mas uso ambas com mais ou menos a mesma frequência (as formas mais enfáticas somente quando eu quero, bem, enfatizar que estou realmente grato, ou entendo que a outra pessoa não precisava agradecer: "Imagina, não fiz nada, você que teve todo o trabalho, eu é que agradeço, etc").

Nunca usei "Obrigado você", mas nunca parei para pensar no motivo (se é que tem).

Comment: Essa do "eu que agradeço" é nova para mim? Qual é o estatuto dessa construção (gíria, coloquial, etc.)? O *é que* é que está consagrado: vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/n%C3%B3s-%C3%A9-quem-agradecemos-ou-n%C3%B3s-%C3%A9-que-agradecemos).

Comment: @Jacinto "eu que agradeço" é bem informal. Deve ser porque quando falado rápido, o "é" antes do "que" acaba sumindo. Mas é só uma suposição minha. De qualquer forma, eu uso bastante e ouço muita gente usando também.

Comment: Poderia existir a forma com quem "Eu quem agradece", mas não se usa, mas pode-se usar o 'que' no lugar do quem "Eu que agradeço"

Answer (score 2):

Já usei os dois (mais ou menos, logo explico), na verdade, e para mim os dois fazem sentido, apesar de achar que "`Obrigado eu`" seja o correto.

No caso de "`Obrigado você`" eu nunca cheguei a usar a expressão dessa maneira. Sempre disse "`Obrigado à você`", o que não fica muito legal, mas que faz um tanto mais de sentido.

E sabendo das transformações que a língua portuguesa sofre com o tempo, não duvidaria que a expressão em questão fosse com o "À" originalmente.

Comment: G.Felicio muito boa a observação que você fez com relação a dizer "Obrigado à você", pois obrigado você fica estranho e não faz sentido. Com apenas uma correção é possível fazer concordância com o sentido que se quer expressar, gratidão pelo ato de outra pessoa.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Na minha opinião, a construção `Obrigado eu` soa muito esquisito. Eu utilizo `Eu que agradeço`.

---

[Este link](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/obrigado-ou-obrigada/) oferece a seguinte informação:

> A palavra obrigado é formada a partir do particípio do verbo obrigar,
>   com sua origem na palavra em latim obligare, **que indica que estamos
>   ligados por laços de agradecimentos à pessoa que nos fez um favor**.
>   Além deste significado principal, ou seja, de estarmos gratos por uma
>   amabilidade, a palavra obrigado significa também aquilo que é imposto
>   por lei, forçado pelas circunstâncias ou imprescindível, sendo
>   sinônimo de obrigatório, imposto, forçado, impelido, sujeito,
>   imperioso, necessário, preciso, entre outros.

A minha interpretação é de que quando alguém nos faz algum gesto e ficamos agradecidos por tal gesto, podemos agradecer com a palavra `Obrigado`. No caso de eu ser um cliente de uma loja, quando o atendente me agradecer (ou por cordialidade ou agradecendo pela preferência, ou qualquer outro motivo), se você também estiver agradecido (ou por questões de cordialidade) e quiser dizer agradecer, o mais adequado parece ser a resposta `Obrigado`. Ao dizer `obrigado` você já está demonstrando que **você** está agradecido, de maneira que acrescentar `eu` seja redundante.

`Obrigado eu` não quer dizer nada para mim. Eu não sei se a pessoa está dizendo que ela está agradecida; a expressão não forma uma frase completa. Isso fica mais evidente se considerarmos `obrigado` como uma interjeição, que dispensa uso de sujeito.

Por outro lado, a expressão `eu que agradeço` passa exatamente a ideia que se queria passar, de maneira clara, objetiva e sem ambiguidades: quem fala a frase está agradecido.

Comment: Em "obrigado, eu" há uma elipse, ou omissão de uma palavra que se subentende: o Miguel diz-me, "obrigado", e eu respondo "obrigado, eu", subentendendo-se "digo" ou "fico" ou "estou" ("obrigado digo eu" = "eu é que digo obrigado"); com "digo" funciona quer se entenda *obrigado* como adjetivo ou interjeição; do mesmo modo "o pequeno, 7 reais" é estranho, mas se for "o sorvete grande custa 10 reais; o pequeno, 5 reais", já se compreende bem.

Answer (score 1):

Acho ruins as duas construções. "Eu é que agradeço" é mais clara, mais elegante, e mais conforme a evolução da língua, em que a origem etimológica da interjeição "obrigado!" tende a ser esquecida.

Mas, de qualquer forma, "obrigado!" vem da frase "Fico-lhe muito obrigado(a)". Para manter a coerência, se **eu** fico "obrigado" **a você**, então as duas construções seguintes são válidas, ainda que canhestras:

> Obrigado(a) eu.
>
> e
>
> Obrigado(a) a você.

Note-se que em ambas as expressões, "obrigado" não é interjeição e portanto deveria flexionar em gênero. Esquisito, portanto, quando a moça te diz "obrigad**o**!" sem flexionar, e você, se for também mulher, teria que responder "obrigad**a** eu"... poderia parecer que você está corrigindo a interlocutora, de forma um tanto grosseira.