# Qual é a origem de "ordenado", no sentido de ’remuneração’?

Tags: origem

Um dos significados de *ordenado* é ’remuneração, salário’. Assim, fico pensando: A palavra *ordenado* ter a mesma raiz de *ordem* é uma coincidência ou há alguma razão por trás? De minha parte, não consigo imaginar qualquer relação entre uma ordem — seja no sentido de comando ou de ordenamento — e uma remuneração.

Comment: Loremlpsum, bem-vindo ao site. Olha, a minha edição foi só uma mariquice: formatei como em obras de linguística -- itálico para mencionar a palavra (o título não aceita itálico, tem de ser aspas) e apóstrofos para significados. Se não gostares, faz rollback ou edita à tua vontade; é a tua pergunta.

Comment: @Jacinto Obrigado pelas boas-vindas e pela edição. Aprendi algo não só com a resposta, mas também com esse seu comentário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é coincidência, não. Olha o que diz o [*Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* de Domingos Vieira de 1873](https://books.google.pt/books?id=z94Qb8-pQ0sC&pg=PA573&dq=%22Cousa,%20merc%C3%AA%20ordenada;%20cousa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT1MDkxLXuAhUSBWMBHTl5Bt8Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Cousa%2C%20merc%C3%AA%20ordenada%3B%20cousa%22&f=false) (grafia original; link ao segundo excerto; não consegui que o Google encontrasse o primeiro, mas encontra-lo subindo duas páginas):

> 1). **ORDENADO** *s. m.* Mantimento, remuneração certa e determinada, legal. Distingue-se dos prés, emolumentos, e mercês particulares por despachos extraordinários.
> […]
> — *Cousa, mercê* **ordenada**; cousa, mercê que se dá, não por despacho, nem desembargo extraordinario, mas por regimento, e ordenança. Vid. **Ordenança**.
> […]
> **ORDENANÇA**, *s. f.* Decreto, ordem, lei, estatuto, ou preceito do legitimo superior, assim espiritual como temporal.
> —Lei, ordenação.

Note-se que o dicionário é de 1873, mas ilustra o uso de *ordenado* com vários exemplos de autores do século XVI, tão perto da origem quanto eu consegui chegar. O que eu tiro destas definições, é que o termo *ordenado* se deve a este tipo de remuneração ser literalmente ordenado. Não simplesmente no sentido que alguém mandou que se pagasse (isso seria verdade também de pagamentos ocasionais), mas que ficou determinado em lei, decreto, estatuto. Isto seria assim no passado. Creio até que o dicionário foi muito conservador (o que é muito útil para quem está interessado na origem do termo): já no princípio do século XIX se encontra *ordenado* no sentido mais lato atual; por exemplo, uma anúncio nesta [Gazeta de Lisboa de 1805](https://books.google.pt/books?id=fWFVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP142&dq=%22bom%20ordenado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiViKWstrXuAhVr5OAKHa5YD9sQ6AEwCXoECAwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22bom%20ordenado%22&f=false), pede um caixeiro, prometendo “hum bom ordenado”.

Antes, em 1720, também o [*Vocabulario Portuguez & Latino* de Raphael Bluteau](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YfMwXg7LS3wC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%22ORDENADO%20fallando%20em%20Leys%22&source=bl&ots=QhygQvMGDP&sig=ACfU3U1j6nMiLzKV_lSIwT3HaIiS2Ad4uw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4lvCRxLXuAhUS8hQKHdSPBtwQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ORDENADO%20fallando%20em%20Leys%22&f=false) relaciona *ordenado* na aceção de ’pagamento, gratificação’ com leis e decretos (negrito meu):

> **ORDENADO**, fallando em Leys, Decretos, ou outra cousa semelhante. *Constitutus*, ou *institutus, a, um. Vid.* Ordenar.
> Ordenado de Ordens Sacras. *Sacris initiatus*.
> **Ordenado**, que se dà a alguem para seu sustento […] **Ordenado** que se dava aos Soldados, que traziam certidões do General, de ter servido bem a Republica [romana] na guerra […] Foy Licinio apresentado pelo Pretor Lucullo ao Conselho da Fazenda, ou Védoria, para ser lançado no livro dos que por seus serviços recebiam **ordenados** da Republica.

Este último exemplo mostra que o ordenado também podia ser uma recompensa por serviços prestados anteriormente: mais uma pensão do que um salário. Também Domingos Vieira dá um exemplo semelhante de Damião de Góis (1502-74): o rei D. Manuel deu a um tal Rui de Sande em reconhecimento dos serviços prestados no seu casamento (do rei, que já tinha acontecido) “mercês, tenças, dinheiro, e ordenados”.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Jacinto, pela resposta excelente e bem amparada! Difìcilmente encontraria tal qualidade em outras partes da Internet.

Comment: @LoremIpsum, língua portuguesa é aqui!

Comment: @LoremIpsum, é pá, obrigado pela bounty. Não era necessário. A satisfação de quem pergunta, que tu já tinhas deixado clara, é a melhor recompensa.

Comment: Por nada, merecido!

Comment: @LoremIpsum, interessante o teu uso de "por nada". Já viste [esta pergunta sobre "de nada" vs "por nada"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/qual-a-origem-e-o-sentido-da-express%c3%a3o-de-nada)?

Comment: Não a vira, Jacinto. Muito interessante.

Answer (score 1):

Os empregados eram "ordenados" a realizar algo, mesmo de forma paga.

- Vou pagar minhas ordens, dizia o chefe ao empregado.
- Vou receber pelos serviços que fui ordenado a fazer - pensa o empregado.

Comment: Isso faria bastante sentido no caso de um empregador dizendo "vou pagar os ordenados", mas carece de sentido no caso do empregado dizer "vou receber meu ordenado", que é uma forma válida (e usada) de se dizer "vou receber meu pagamento".

Comment: Desculpe, acho que não me compreendeu: eu realmente coloquei "ordenado" na segunda frase com a intenção explicar a palavra. Respondi por uma opção de início da invenção da palavra. Se eu começasse dizendo que o chefe  "vai pagar os ordenados", Qual o sentido da explicação? Afinal, foi essa a pergunta...